# ExtJs multiselect combobox with checkboxes list

Tags: javascript, extjs, checkbox, combobox, extjs6

How to implement ExtJs multiselect combobox with checkboxes list? Documentation for ExtJs6 says that option multiSelect is deprecated.

Comment: Have you tried giving that config in extjs6? If it doesnt work please give its fiddle link.

Comment: I don't wont to use deprecated config because it will be a trouble in the feature.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation holds the answer:

> Deprecated since version 5.1.0
>
> Use [Ext.form.field.Tag](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.form.field.Tag.html) or [Ext.view.MultiSelector](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.view.MultiSelector.html)

The `multiSelect` doesn't work on a combobox for all sorts of valid reasons; don't bother trying it.